# Difference between outputs of same query as search and subsearch

Tags: splunk

Why is it that the following Splunk search:

```
search sourcetype=srt  | table serialNumber
```

will give me a one-column table of serial numbers as expected, while the same query in subsearch brackets

```
[search sourcetype=srt  | table serialNumber]
```

does not return the same table that I expect, but rather returns the full record?

The documentation seems to suggest that both results should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Splunk documentation regarding subsearches: [Use a subsearch](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchTutorial/Useasubsearch)

In simple terms, you can use a subsearch to filter events from a primary search.

A subsearch does not remove fields/columns from the primary search. To do that, you will need an additional table command.

Have a look at this example:

```
index=m1 sourcetype=srt1 [ search index=m2 sourcetype=srt2 | table serialNumber]
| table _time,host,serialNumber
```

First, the subsearch is run which returns a couple of serialNumbers. Next, the primary search is run, disregarding any events with a serialNumber not contained in the subsearch. Lastly, a table is created based on fields available in the primary search.